# How to pass variable value into URL using cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am working on Cypress API Automation task and want to pass value to an endpoint. I fetched value from postgress database and stored it in a variable called **user_id**. But I am facing issue while hitting endpoint.

**Value fetched from database:**

> log[{user_id: 52}]

**Issue:**

```
cy.request() failed on:

http://localhost:8080/user/[object%20Object]

The response we received from your web server was:
```

**Below is my Code**

```
it.only('Delete User', ()=>{
   let user_id = cy.task("connectDB","select user_id from user_details where first_name='XYZ'").then(cy.log);
cy.request({
    method:'DELETE',
    url:'localhost:8080/user/'+user_id+'' 
}).then((res) => {
    expect(res.status).to.eq(200);
})
})
```

**I want to pass '52' as a value to the endpoint, Can someone help here ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I am able to solve my problem using this approach**

**Below is my Spec File:**

```
    it("Database Test", () => {
  cy.task("READFROMDB",
  {
    dbConfig: Cypress.config('DB'),
    sql:'select * from "user_details"'
  }).then((result) =>
  {
    //console.log(result.rows)
    let user_id = result.rows[0].user_id
    console.log("user id is :"+user_id)
  })
});
```

**Below is my Cypress.config.js File:**

```
const {defineConfig} = require("cypress");
const pg= require("pg")

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e:{
    setupNodeEvents(on,config){
        on("task",{
          READFROMDB({dbConfig,sql}){
            const client = new pg.Pool(dbConfig);
            return client.query(sql);
          }
        })
    },
    DB:{
      user: "postgres",
      password: "password",
      host: "localhost",
      database: "postgres",
      port: '5432'
    },
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

`cy.task()` needs to use `.then()` to get the value, like [this example](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task#Save-a-variable-across-non-same-origin-URL-visits).

```js
cy.task("connectDB", "select user_id from user_details where first_name='XYZ'")
  .then(user_id => {
    cy.request({
      method: 'DELETE',
      url: 'localhost:8080/user/' + user_id
    }).then((res) => {
      expect(res.status).to.eq(200)                // passes
    })
  })
```

If you try to assign the return to a variable `let user_id = cy.task("connectDB"...` you will get a chainer object, but it's not much use without a `.then()` to extract the value.

Comment: Implemented your way as well getting same error. it.only('DELETE USER',()=>{
    cy.task("connectDB", "select user_id from user_details where first_name='XYZ'")
    .then(user_id => {
      cy.request({
        method: 'DELETE',
        url: 'localhost:8080/user/' + user_id
      }).then((res) => {
        expect(res.status).to.eq(200)
      })
    })
})

Answer (score 0):

```
cy.url().should('include', '/user_id')
```

docs: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/url#Differences

or if that did not help, try looking at these docs: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-1-configuration-file

Comment: Where should i use your peice of use ? I am beginner in javascript and cypress. I want to create this URL http://localhost:8080/user/52 instead of  http://localhost:8080/user/[object%20Object]

Comment: is it only for user/52? or can the number change depending on the user logged in?

Comment: For time being value 52 is constant and i have to access it from DB.

Answer (score 0):

Your error pretty much says it all. `user_id` is an object. You'll have to access the property to pass the correct value, which would be `user_id[0].user_id`

```js
it.only('Delete User', ()=>{
   let user_id = cy.task("connectDB","select user_id from user_details where first_name='XYZ'").then(cy.log);
cy.request({
    method:'DELETE',
    url:'localhost:8080/user/'+ user_id[0].user_id
}).then((res) => {
    expect(res.status).to.eq(200);
})
})
```

Comment: Tried this one but not working. Got this error.                                                   
cy.request() failed on:

http://localhost:8080/user/undefined

The response we received from your web server was:

> 400: Bad Request

Comment: Forgot your task returned an array of objects.